# Can't install jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, gallery

I want to install the gallery and instead of using flash I wish to use [this](https://github.com/suprb/Grid-A-Licious) jQuery plugin. I cannot figure out how do I install and use it since it is distributed as .zip archive with two .js files inside and no index file or .css at all.

[Here's](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/) plug in features demo, which I would like to achieve.

Comment: Why not view the page source for the demo? That would give you the HTML markup and links to any CSS

Comment: I think you're thinking of plugins like traditional computer software with installation GUI and all that.. it's linking up the appropriate scripts and executing (initializing) the right objects. Welcome to OOP. Sink or swim time! :)

Comment: I did and still there trying to understand it :)

Comment: @DrydenLong That project lacks really basic documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").gridalicious({
  animate: true,
  animationOptions: {
    queue: true,
    speed: 200,
    duration: 300,
    effect: 'fadeInOnAppear',
    complete: onComplete
  }
});
```

As per the source code...

The CSS is set in the JS itself, no need for an external style sheet.

If you'll scroll down http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/, you will see how to initialize it. It appears to just be a collection of `div`s with the class `item` inside of the initialized container.. `<div id="container">` for example.

## Update:

```
<!doctype html5>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test of plugin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.grid-a-licious.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <!--I assume it asks for divs with the "item" class, but it may be added automatically.-->
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript>
    //The initialize code printed above. Has parameters (read:options) you can tweak.
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new in this, and know that maybe jumped too soon into complicated part of coding. I am still not sure how would you apply this in Dreamwever do I just link to js file like : 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.grid-a-licious.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.grid-a-licious.min.js"></script>

because in the plug ins that I have installed before it would be something like: link to CDN then link to js and stye sheet and then div tags where you put images.

And I dont seem to find the div tags you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: Provided that those files are in the same directory as the file you're trying to execute them on (i.e., `index.html`). You'll also need to load jQuery prior to the plugins, since they rely on it.

Comment: P.S. - **you don't need both** - the later is the minified (read: production) version of the code. They do the same, one's just smaller for better load times and the other is human readable.

Comment: @user3303253 Just saw the comment about not finding the `<div>` tags - an valuable resource is Firefox's developer tools for HTML and CSS, and I recommend Firebug for debugging javascript. If you use the inspector tool, you can see what's going on in the source code.

Comment: Thank you will try, figure it out